# Please guide me, my program is not working and showing error id return 1 exit status

Tags: c++

**[Error] ld returned 1 exit status . Getting this error while executing although all code is fine then why this is showing and program is not executing**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void addition(int ,int );
int main()
{
    int num1,num2,add;
    cout<<"Enter first number: ";
    cin>>num1;
    cout<<"Enter second number: ";
    cin>>num2;
    addition(num1,num2);
    cout<<"Addition is: "<<add<<endl;
    return 0;
}

void addition(int a,int b)
{
    int c= a+b;
    cout<<c;
}
```

Comment: You do not initialize `add` value.

Comment: `"although all code is fine"` - A bold claim, considering the code isn't working.

Comment: Apart from not using `add` while uninitilized, which is a compilation error on VS but shouldn't cause runtime errors, this code works just fine for me (I set `add` to 0 at deceleration)

Comment: no compiler errors does not mean that the code is fine. Even if you would not get runtime errors, that alone is not sufficient to conclude the code is fine

Comment: Did you call `gcc` instead of `g++` to compile your program?

Comment: If you use `gcc` to build the program, it will not find the C++ standard library. If you use `g++` it will. And BTW, the command failing is `ld` (ell-dee) not `id`.

Comment: @David 'a bold claim' given the text is in bold, you sir get a +1 for your pun!

Comment: Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) before attempting to ask more questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I compiled your code using g++ and then run the binary. Result shown below:

```
Enter first number: 10
Enter second number: 20
30Addition is: 0
```

I did not get an error when executing the binary however, like others have already pointed out, there is one error in your code. I guess your intention was to store the sum in variable "add". To do that you need this line of code before you print add:

```
add = addition(num1, num2);
```

But your function addition returns a void, this needs to be changed to return an int as shown below:

```
int addition(int, int);
```

The function body can be like shown below:

```
int addition(int a, int b){return a+b;}
```

A suggested rewrite of your code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int addition(const int& a, const int& b){return a+b;}

int main()
{
    int num1{};
    int num2{};

    cout<<"Enter first number: ";
    cin>>num1;

    cout<<"Enter second number: ";
    cin>>num2;

    int&& add = addition(num1,num2);
    cout<<"Addition is: "<<add<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

compile the code using g++ -std=c++11

Comment: Thanks .. i got it

Comment: In this case agreed. The '&' does not add much benefit. But i mentioned it here as references ,both lvalue reference and rvalue reference , is a good feature to learn.

Comment: It only adds overhead. It’s the worst kind of premature optimisation, a pessimisation, which is not a good ”feature” to learn.